# Conditional formatting possibly ignoring first rule

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm no expert, but I know enough to be dangerous. So thanks in advance for any help

I have the following Conditional rules (In the order given, with stop if true for each one)

```
=E5="TRUE" (Green Fill)

=ISBLANK(G5)=TRUE (no format)

=(Today()-G5)>4 (Red Fill)
```

There's a few other colors based on other days, but you get the idea.

It's the first one that's giving me issue.  E5 is populated based on a checkbox (D5) being checked or not (True if checked, False if Unchecked).  This was created by format control in the textbox (Control tab).

So, the basic logic tree is:

```
If completed, GREEN FILL

If date field = null, no format

If date field age > 4, RED FILL
```

My initial suspect was that E5 is not actually populated with True or False, but then I remembered I have the following to let me know the number of completed tasks (Which works correctly):

```
=COUNTIFS(A5:A100, "<>", E5:E100, TRUE)
```

Based on that, I tried both with and without quotes for the first condition, but get the same result (zilch)

So, I'm open to suggestions on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first rule should look like this - without the quotes.

```
=E5=TRUE
```

Otherwise its looking for a string value saying TRUE in the cell instead of the boolean TRUE.